# Angular & Tailwind - Dynamically change the colour of a slider thumb?

Tags: angular, dynamic, colors, slider, tailwind-css

I have been trying for a whole day now to try and change the colour of the accent/thumb/control of a slider and I cannot seem to get it right. It's easy to set a colour if you're not planning on dynamically changing the colour of it at any point (for instance, a user changing its colour using a colour selector).

Using Angular 14 & TailwindCSS.

My current solution makes use of the selector `[&::-webkit-slider-thumb]`, which works fine if you just want to set the colour and call it a day. I've tried using `[ngClass]` but the colour just doesn't update no matter what I try.

I have also tried making a function that looks like this:

```
public get sliderClasses(): string {
    return `[&::-webkit-slider-thumb]:bg-[${this.primary}] [&::-webkit-slider-thumb:active]:bg-[${this.secondary}]`;
}
```

Primary & Secondary are just hex codes e.g #FF0000

Trying to use this on `[ngClass]`, it also does nothing. Any ideas?

---

**Wongjn's Suggestion:**

I have just tried this solution suggested by @Wongjn, however there's no value in --primary so the background is just transparent. Using a simple button to test the solution.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" [style]="{'--primary': '#000'}" class="bg-[--primary]">
```

**Working Solution:**

This is the correct solution but needed a little bit of editing, below is the working solution, thanks to @Wongjn!

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" [style]="{'--primary': '#000'}" class="bg-[var(--primary)]">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using the `style` attribute like:

```js
@Component({
  template: `
<div
  [class]="sliderClasses"
  [style]="{
    '--primary': primary,
    '--seconday': secondary
  }"
>…</div>`,
})

export class Component {
  primary = '#f00';
  secondary = '#0f0';
  public get sliderClasses(): string {
    return "[&::-webkit-slider-thumb]:bg-[--primary] [&::-webkit-slider-thumb:active]:bg-[--secondary]";
  };
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast reply, I appreciate it. Will try this out!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, does setting style variables only work in templates inside the component file or should it also work in a separate HTML file linked via templateUrl?

Comment: It should also work in a separate HTML file linked via `templateUrl`.

Comment: Weird, --primary and --secondary aren't returning the values I set, even if I just set it to a flat #000

Comment: Oh, I think I got it working! I had to use "bg-[var(--primary)]"